# Asynchronous toggle button using a semaphore to avoid service load

Tags: c#, xaml, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, binding

I have a Windows Phone client with a skinned toggle button, which is acting as a "favourite" button. The checked property is then two-way bound to the ViewModel (standard MVVM pattern).

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.IsFavouriteUser, ElementName=PageRoot, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

When the bound boolean is changed, I want to initiate an asynchronous network call to the service.

```
    public bool IsFavouriteUser
    {
        get { return _isFavouriteUser; }
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _isFavouriteUser, value))
            {
                // Dispatches the state change to a RESTful service call
                // in a background thread.
                SetFavouriteState();
            }
        }
    }
```

If the user presses the button multiple times, then many Add / Remove asynchronous service calls could be made - Hypothetically these take 2 seconds to do the network round-trip and service processing.

In the past I have used something like:

```
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

    // I would probably dispatch this call to a background thread in the real client
    public async Task<bool> SetFavouriteState()
    {
        try
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

            bool result;

            if (IsFavouriteUser)
            {
                result = await ServiceClient.AddAsync(x);
            }
            else
            {
                result = await ServiceClient.RemoveAsync(x);
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            // I wouldn't use an empty catch in production code
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
```

However this could endlessly queue up user input; whereas the service is only interested in the latest user event - on or off - and the UI should remain responsive to user input.

- What is the best way to ensure that the client doesn't send "Add/Remove/Add/Remove" if the user repeatedly hits the button. i.e. I want to ignore the middle two events and only send "Add, wait for response to complete, Remove".
- Is there a better way to bind to this boolean property in an asynchronous way?
- What is the best way to lock my model so that only one request in this context is ongoing at any point?
- What is the best way to inform the user that something is happening while we wait for the call to happen (and maybe fail)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several good patterns to deal with async re-entrancy, i.e. what happens if a user action invokes an async method while it's already in-flight. I wrote an article with several patterns here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2014/03/03/async-re-entrancy-and-the-patterns-to-deal-with-it.aspx

I think your problem is a special case of pattern 5 (code below).

However, please note an oddity in your specification. It's possible that the user clicks quickly enough that you get the sequence Add followed by Add (e.g. if the intervening Remove didn't get a chance to even start executing before the second click to Add arrived). So please protect against this in your own scenario-specific way.

```
 async  Task  Button1Click()
 {
     // Assume we're being called on UI thread... if not, the two assignments must be made atomic.
     // Note: we factor out "FooHelperAsync" to avoid an await between the two assignments. 
     // without an intervening await. 
      if  (FooAsyncCancellation !=  null ) FooAsyncCancellation.Cancel();
      FooAsyncCancellation  =  new  CancellationTokenSource ();
      FooAsyncTask  = FooHelperAsync(FooAsyncCancellation.Token);

      await  FooAsyncTask;
 }

 Task  FooAsyncTask;
 CancellationTokenSource  FooAsyncCancellation;

 async  Task  FooHelperAsync( CancellationToken  cancel)
 {
      try  {  if  (FooAsyncTask !=  null )  await  FooAsyncTask; }
      catch  ( OperationCanceledException ) { }
     cancel.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      await  FooAsync(cancel);
 }

 async  Task  FooAsync( CancellationToken  cancel)
 {
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest disabling the `ToggleButton` button and showing indeterminate `ProgressBar` when the request is fired and hiding the `ProgressBar` and enabling the `ToggleButton` when it finishes.